# what is this 0=1 in lamda capture in the following code and 0++ % xy in the following code?

Tags: c++, lambda

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int xy = 4;
 
    using Cell = std::array<unsigned char, 8>;
 
    std::array<Cell, xy * xy> board;
 
    board.fill({ {0xE2, 0x96, 0x84, 0xE2, 0x96, 0x80, 0, 0} }); // "▄▀";
 
    std::for_each(board.cbegin(), board.cend(), [xy, O=1](const auto& c) mutable
    {
        std::cout << c.data() << ((O++ % xy) ? "" : "\n");
    });
}
```

This is the link for the same.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill

Comment: Link to earlier version for reference: https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/container/array/fill&oldid=122261

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a capital O. In the font used on cppreference for code zero has a dot in the middle and O doesn't.

I changed the name `O` to `count`, hope it saves confusion for someone in the future.