# Why random_shuffle uses std::swap rather than std::iter_swap?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have this algorithm `std::random_shuffle` possible implementation from cppreference:

> ```
> template< class RandomIt >
> void random_shuffle( RandomIt first, RandomIt last )
> {
>     typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::difference_type i, n;
>    n = last - first;
>    for (i = n-1; i > 0; --i) {
>        using std::swap;
>        swap(first[i], first[std::rand() % (i+1)]);
>        // rand() % (i+1) isn't actually correct, because the generated number
>        // is not uniformly distributed for most values of i. A correct implementation
>       // will need to essentially reimplement C++11 std::uniform_int_distribution,
>       // which is beyond the scope of this example.
>   }
> }
> ```

```
int main(){

    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());
    for (auto i : v)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The output:

```
3 7 6 2 1 4 5 8
```

- The algorithm works just fine but why does it use `std::swap` rather than `std::iter_swap` in `swap(first[i], first[std::rand() % (i+1)]);` ?

So it can easily be this way:

```
std::iter_swap(first + i, first + std::rand() % (i + 1) );
```

And it will work the same way. So is there a benefit of using `std::swap` rather than `std::iter_swap`?

Comment: Actually, [libc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/d9375e490072d1aae73a93949aa158fcd2a27018/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L4551) uses `std::iter_swap` internally. I don't think there's any difference, whoever wrote the example just chose one version they thought was easier to digest.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Any idea who that "whoever" might be? ([Rumour has it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68282166/10871073) that you have an element of 'insider-info' on the cppreference site. xD)

Comment: @AdrianMole All I have is the [diff page](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp%2Falgorithm%2Frandom_shuffle&diff=126147&oldid=1536) which is available to everyone ;) It seems the example was using `std::swap` from when the page was first written in 2011 (and examples for the other overloads followed), so I guess nobody though that changing it to `iter_swap` would be an improvement. Since this is a wiki, such a change can be done by anyone, or someone could start a discussion for that page - maybe there really is a reason to stick to `std::swap` in the example.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen OK. Thanks for the clarification. I thought you were one of the Powers behind cppreference ... my illusions are duly shattered!